# ECDSA Signatures always return false on verification

Tags: java, digital-signature, ecdsa

I have 3 test keys — RSA, DSA and ECDSA. The RSA and DSA key-based signatures return true when verified. But the ECDSA-based signature always returns false (even when the signatures match).

The same code is used to verify all 3 test keys (apart from the differences in the provider object passed to `Signature.getInstance()`). My code is as follows:

```
Signature ecdsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withECDSA");
ecdsa.initSign(pk);
ecdsa.update(rawKeyBytes);
byte[] signatureBytes = ecdsa.sign(); 

Signature ecdsa3 = Signature.getInstance("SHA1WithECDSA");
ecdsa3.initVerify(puk);  
ecdsa3.update(rawKeyBytes);
System.out.println("Verifying: "+ecdsa3.verify(signatureBytes));
```

The output of the program is always `Verifying: false`. When I change the provider to `SHA1WithRSA` and use an RSA key (using the same code above), the verification returns true, same with DSA-based keys. Someone mentioned it had something to do with the `ECPoint` passed to the `ECPublicKeySpec()` constructor, when trying to create a public key from the private key like this:

```
ECPrivateKey ec = (ECPrivateKey) privateKey;
ECPublicKeySpec ecKeySpec = new ECPublicKeySpec(
    ec.getParams().getGenerator(),
    ec.getParams()
);
```

Someone mentioned that signature verification (using the public key) would fail if a different `ECPoint` was used from the private key. But I actually get the `ECPoint` from the `PrivateKey` object (`ec`). Any solutions, please?

Comment: Nope, this link doesn't solve the problem. (I actually used the approach mentioned there to create the signature). The problem here is that the signature won't verify.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography Stack Exchange. Please note that this site is more about the theoretical (mathematical) aspects of cryptography, not about usage of specific crypto libraries. As such, I'm migrating your question to our sister site Stack Overflow.

Comment: Are you sure ECPublicKeySpec constructor takes generator as the first argument?

Comment: @dchest ECPublicKeySpec takes the following parameters ECPublicKeySpec(ECPoint w, ECParameterSpec params) according to this link (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/spec/ECPublicKeySpec.html). The "ec.getParams().getGenerator()" returns an ECPoint object, hence it's use here.

Comment: @DeepCoder I think this should be a public point, not generator (it's already specified in EC parameters). Otherwise, where do you put your public point? :-)

Comment: @dchest, Thanks. So what in your opinion is the best way to construct a public ECPoint - given an EC private key in Java? Note that my requirements do not permit me to use BouncyCastle.

Comment: @DeepCoder Sorry, I'm not a Java programmer; but in ECDSA, public key point is the result of scalar multiplication of curve's base point and private key.